# Filter a collection with LINQ vs CollectionView

Tags: wpf, linq, datagrid, filter, nscollectionview

I want to filter a ObservableCollection with max 3000 items in a DataGrid with 6 columns. The user should be able to filter in an "&&"-way all 6 columns.

Should I use LINQ or a CollectionView for it? LINQ seemed faster trying some www samples. Do you have any pro/cons?

**UPDATE**:

```
private ObservableCollection<Material> _materialList;
        private ObservableCollection<Material> _materialListInternal;

        public MaterialBrowserListViewModel()
        {           
              _materialListInternal = new ObservableCollection<Material>();          

            for (int i = 0; i < 2222; i++)
            {
                var mat = new Material()
                {
                    Schoolday = DateTime.Now.Date,
                    Period = i,
                    DocumentName = "Excel Sheet" + i,
                    Keywords = "financial budget report",
                    SchoolclassCode = "1",
                };
                _materialListInternal.Add(mat);
                var mat1 = new Material()
                {
                    Schoolday = DateTime.Now.Date,
                    Period = i,
                    DocumentName = "Word Doc" + i,
                    Keywords = "Economical staticstics report",
                    SchoolclassCode = "2",
                };
                _materialListInternal.Add(mat1);
            }

            MaterialList = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MaterialListInternal);
            MaterialList.Filter = new Predicate<object>(ContainsInFilter); 
        }      

        public bool ContainsInFilter(object item)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterKeywords))
                return true;   

            Material material = item as Material;
            if (DocumentHelper.ContainsCaseInsensitive(material.Keywords,FilterKeywords,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))        
                return true;          
            else          
                return false;                     
        }

        private string _filterKeywords;
        public string FilterKeywords
        {
            get { return _filterKeywords; }
            set
            {
                if (_filterKeywords == value)
                    return;

                _filterKeywords = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("FilterKeywords");
                MaterialList.Refresh();               
            }
        }

        public ICollectionView MaterialList { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Material> MaterialListInternal
        {
            get { return _materialListInternal; }
            set
            {
                _materialListInternal = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("MaterialList");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

- Using ICollectionView gives you automatic collection changed notifications when you call Refresh. Using LINQ you'll need to fire your own change notifications when the filter needs to be re-run to update the UI. Not difficult, but requires a little more thought than just calling Refresh.
- LINQ is more flexible that the simple yes/no filtering used by ICollectionView, but if you're not doing something complex there's not really any advantage to that flexibility.
- As Henk stated, there shouldn't be a noticable performance difference in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

For an interactive (DataGrid?) experience you should probabaly use the CollectionView. For a more code-oriented sorting, LINQ.

And with max 3000 items, speed should not be a (major) factor in a UI.

Comment: I am using a CollectionViewSource filter just ONE column at the moment. Do you know why the collection is only updated when I put the .Refresh() method in the below property?   private string _filterKeywords
        public string FilterKeywords
        {
            get { return _filterKeywords; }
            set
            {
                if (_filterKeywords == value)
                    return;

                _filterKeywords = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("FilterKeywords");
                MaterialList.Refresh();               
            }
        }

Comment: "Do you know why ..." - No, but maybe if you add that code to the question I might be able to read it.

Answer (score 1):

How about both? Thomas Levesque built a LINQ-enabled wrapper around `ICollectionView`.

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<Person> people;

// Using query comprehension
var query =
    from p in people.ShapeView()
    where p.Age >= 18
    orderby p.LastName, p.FirstName
    group p by p.Country;

query.Apply();

// Using extension methods
people.ShapeView()
      .Where(p => p.Age >= 18)
      .OrderBy(p => p.LastName)
      .ThenBy(p => p.FirstName)
      .Apply();
```

Code:

```
public static class CollectionViewShaper
{
    public static CollectionViewShaper<TSource> ShapeView<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(source);
        return new CollectionViewShaper<TSource>(view);
    }

    public static CollectionViewShaper<TSource> Shape<TSource>(this ICollectionView view)
    {
        return new CollectionViewShaper<TSource>(view);
    }
}

public class CollectionViewShaper<TSource>
{
    private readonly ICollectionView _view;
    private Predicate<object> _filter;
    private readonly List<SortDescription> _sortDescriptions = new List<SortDescription>();
    private readonly List<GroupDescription> _groupDescriptions = new List<GroupDescription>();

    public CollectionViewShaper(ICollectionView view)
    {
        if (view == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("view");
        _view = view;
        _filter = view.Filter;
        _sortDescriptions = view.SortDescriptions.ToList();
        _groupDescriptions = view.GroupDescriptions.ToList();
    }

    public void Apply()
    {
        using (_view.DeferRefresh())
        {
            _view.Filter = _filter;
            _view.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            foreach (var s in _sortDescriptions)
            {
                _view.SortDescriptions.Add(s);
            }
            _view.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
            foreach (var g in _groupDescriptions)
            {
                _view.GroupDescriptions.Add(g);
            }
        }
    }

    public CollectionViewShaper<TSource> ClearGrouping()
    {
        _groupDescriptions.Clear();
        return this;
    }

    public CollectionViewShaper<TSource> ClearSort()
    {
        _sortDescriptions.Clear();
        return this;
    }

    public CollectionViewShaper<TSource> ClearFilter()
    {
        _filter = null;
        return this;
    }

    public CollectionViewShaper<TSource> ClearAll()
    {
        _filter = null;
        _sortDescriptions.Clear();
        _groupDescriptions.Clear();
        return this;
    }

    public CollectionViewShaper<TSource> Where(Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        _filter = o => predicate((TSource)o);
        return this;
    }

    public CollectionViewShaper<TSource> OrderBy<TKey>(Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        return OrderBy(keySelector, true, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }

    public CollectionViewShaper<TSource> OrderByDescending<TKey>(Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        return OrderBy(keySelector, true, ListSortDirection.Descending);
    }

    public CollectionViewShaper<TSource> ThenBy<TKey>(Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        return OrderBy(keySelector, false, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }

    public CollectionViewShaper<TSource> ThenByDescending<TKey>(Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        return OrderBy(keySelector, false, ListSortDirection.Descending);
    }

    private CollectionViewShaper<TSource> OrderBy<TKey>(Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, bool clear, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        string path = GetPropertyPath(keySelector.Body);
        if (clear)
            _sortDescriptions.Clear();
        _sortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(path, direction));
        return this;
    }

    public CollectionViewShaper<TSource> GroupBy<TKey>(Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        string path = GetPropertyPath(keySelector.Body);
        _groupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(path));
        return this;
    }

    private static string GetPropertyPath(Expression expression)
    {
        var names = new Stack<string>();
        var expr = expression;
        while (expr != null && !(expr is ParameterExpression) && !(expr is ConstantExpression))
        {
            var memberExpr = expr as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpr == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("The selector body must contain only property or field access expressions");
            names.Push(memberExpr.Member.Name);
            expr = memberExpr.Expression;
        }
        return String.Join(".", names.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Credit:
http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/11/30/wpf-using-linq-to-shape-data-in-a-collectionview/

Answer (score 0):

Based on a visual complexity and number of items there really WILL be a noticable performance difference since the Refresh method recreates the whole view!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need my [ObservableComputations](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations) library. Using this library you can code like this:

```C#
ObservableCollection<Material> MaterialList = MaterialListInternal.Filtering(m => 
     String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterKeywords) 
     || DocumentHelper.ContainsCaseInsensitive(
         material.Keywords, FilterKeywords, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

MaterialList reflects all the changes in the MaterialListInternal collection. Do not forget to add the implementation of the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface to Material class, so that MaterialList collection reflects the changes in material.Keywords property.